# Adding discrete probability distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have two random variables, $X$ and $Y$, where $X$ has a binomial distribution $\text{Binomial}(2, 0.5)$ and $Y$ has uniform distribution with probability 0.25.

I need to find the probability distribution of the random variable $Z = \frac{X + Y}{2}$, but I have no idea how to add a binomial distribution with a uniform one.

Comment: What is a "uniform distribution with probability $0.25$"? It's _discrete_, remember?